# Not able to publish the table written in MD file

Tags: html, markdown

The code i am using is:

| Operator | Unary/Binary | Description | Notes |

| -------- |------------ | ----------- | ----- |

|   ||   | B           |Concatenation| Concatenation also applies to binary types|
| LIKE     |  B          | String pattern comparison |  LIKE  [ESCAPE ] |

But the output i am getting is like this (In paragraph):

Operator | Unary/Binary | Description | Notes | | ——– |———— | ———– | —– | | || | B |Concatenation| Concatenation also applies to binary types| | LIKE | B | String pattern comparison | LIKE [ESCAPE ] | | SIMILAR TO | B | String pattern comparison | SIMILAR TO [ESCAPE ]|

Please help

Comment: Please use code formatting. Indent all code lines with 4 spaces.

Comment: Make sure that empty cells are indented with at least 4 spaces. Pay attention that markdown tables do not support multiline cells, colspan and rowspan.